# How to automatically delete any entity when all its relationships are nil?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a simple Core Data app that has a many to many relationship from entity A to B. I have kept the delete rule as `nullify`.

I simply want that when all entities of type A that relate to an entity of type B are deleted. In other words, when all relationships from a given B to A are nil, that particularly object of entity B should be deleted.

Now I noticed that, at least for me, this isn't happening automatically. Do I have to manually check to see if a given B object has all relationship to A as `nil` and then delete them manually or is there an automatic way to achieve it?

Comment: In my case, Only children can be deleted and not the parent. And I want that when all children of a given parent are deleted, the parent object should be removed from the store as well. the parent cannot be directly deleted. The same issue happened is there any other solution? Cascade was working for you or not?

Answer (score 4):

> ...or is there an automatic way to have this happen?

Yes if you let Core Data to manage this.

If you have two entites, say `Parent` and `Child` where the former has a one-to-many relationships with the latter

[image]

you can set the `children` relationship with a Delete Rule **Cascade**.

[image]

On the contrary, the `parent` relationship would be

[image]

The check on the `optional` flag depends on if a `Child` could exist with or without a `Parent` associated with it.

Here the delete rules mean the following.

*If I delete a parent, all the children will be deleted. If I delete a child, nothing would happen on the parent (in other words the parent won't be deleted).*

The inverse relatioship between the `Child` and the `Parent` is very important since lets Core Data to maintain the graph consistency. So, you should (a must for me) use it in every model you have.

Is this what you want to achieve? Let me know if you need something else.

**Update 1**

> Only children can be deleted and not the parent. And I want that when
>   all children of a given parent are deleted, the parent object should
>   be removed from the store as well. the parent cannot be directly
>   deleted.

Deleting a parent it's up to you. In your code you will just not delete a parent if you want. I would use the configuration I provided since, if you delete a child, the parent will remove the reference to it.

To delete all the children that belong to a specific parent I would use a simple fetch request against `Child` where the predicate would be

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent == %@", parentOfTheChildrenYouWantToDelete];
```

Once run, the request will return a `NSArray` of managed objects. `for in` to delete them.

Comment: just for note: 'cascade' deletion which is done by Core Data is not optimized in any way (it simple fetches or resolves faults one by one for all rel objects and after that deletes them one by one) so you can encounter a delay problem if your object has a lot of relations

Comment: In my case, Only children can be deleted and not the parent. And I want that when all children of a given parent are deleted, the parent object should be removed from the store as well. the parent cannot be directly deleted.

Comment: the central entity of my app is the child and not the parent, as an example.

Comment: @flexaddicted see the way it goes in my apps logic is that the user 'primarily' deals with Children, selectively adding them to different parents. they can add or delete a child. They can also add or delete a parent. and in my app, one parent can have multiple children and 1 child can have many parents. now if all parents of a child are deleted, the child still continues to exist but if all children if a parent are deleted, the parent should cease to exist. so what should be the delete rule from child to parent? or do i have to manually delete the parent once the NSSet of its children is Null?

Comment: In my case, Only children can be deleted and not the parent. And I want that when all children of a given parent are deleted, the parent object should be removed from the store as well. the parent cannot be directly deleted. The same issue happened is there any other solution?

Answer (score 4):

In your `NSManagedObject` subclass

```
- (void)willSave
{
  // Check for relationship and delete self if empty
}
```

Comment: So i should call on the deleteObject method of the MOC from here and give it a 'self'. But how do i get a reference to the MOC?

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding of your question, I recommend you look into running a specific fetch at a certain point in your code to check for nil against the relationship, and then delete manually.

So to answer your question, my understanding is that there is no "automatic" mechanism.

Comment: So from what you are suggesting, I should fetch the associated objects at the relationship end and see if their NSSet has become Null, and if it has, I should delete that object?

Comment: Yes that is what I am suggesting - a manual code check. so you could embed an `NSFetch` into your code that, as you mention, checks the `NSSet` for nil, and if that is the case, then delete the current "parent".